# AGPBI: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found

Tags: android, android-studio

` cannot be accesed and its giving me this logcat error

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Tag \u003cItem\u003e can not appear inside \u003cstring-array\u003e, only \u003citem\u003e","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values\\strings.xml","position":{"startLine":6,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":298,"endLine":10,"endColumn":19,"endOffset":429}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-hdpi-v4\\values-hdpi-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027barLength\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.4.0\\res\\values-hdpi-v4\\values-hdpi-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":6,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":327}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027drawableSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.4.0\\res\\values-hdpi-v4\\values-hdpi-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":6,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":327}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027gapBetweenBars\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\appcompat-v7\\23.4.0\\res\\values-hdpi-v4\\values-hdpi-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":6,"endColumn":13,"endOffset":327}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-sw600dp-v13\\values-sw600dp-v13.xml","position":{"startLine":22}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabGravity\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\design\\23.4.0\\res\\values-sw600dp-v13\\values-sw600dp-v13.xml","position":{"startLine":11,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":677,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":854}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabMode\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\design\\23.4.0\\res\\values-sw600dp-v13\\values-sw600dp-v13.xml","position":{"startLine":11,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":677,"endLine":14,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":854}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-land\\values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":8}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabGravity\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\design\\23.4.0\\res\\values-land\\values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":5,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":232}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource found that matches the given name: attr \u0027tabMode\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\exploded-aar\\com.android.support\\design\\23.4.0\\res\\values-land\\values-land.xml","position":{"startLine":2,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":55,"endLine":5,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":232}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-large-v4\\values-large-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":13}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-large-v4\\values-large-v4.xml","position":{"startLine":14}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":2}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":3}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Dialog\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":4}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":5}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":6}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":7}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-night-v8\\values-night-v8.xml","position":{"startLine":8}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-v11\\values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":40}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Squirrel\\Documents\\MyCodes\\ClickAwayTechnologies\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\values-v11\\values-v11.xml","position":{"startLine":45}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
```

after a brief research i learnt that the cause of my error is

```
<string-array name="tabs">
        <Item>Tab 1</Item>
        <Item>Tab 2</Item>
        <Item>Tab 3</Item>
    </string-array>
```

I am trying  to resolve it but i cant get the best way to resolve it can some one help.

This section of my code

```
pager.setAdapter(new viewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new pager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
```

is showing an error by not recognizing the function

```
SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
```

i could also appreciate if i could resolve this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix all the above errors.
The cause for the AGPBI was because i was using the tag `<Item>`
So i swapped it to

```
<string-array name="tabs">
        <item>Tab 1</item>
        <item>Tab 2</item>
        <item>Tab 3</item>
    </string-array>
```

for the next issue i had to cal a new class `ViewPager` instead of the earlier initialized class pager so now my code looks like.

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
```

and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change the `compileSDKVersion` to match the support library versions to get rid of this error.

My support library version was `27.1.1` whereas the `compileSDKVersion` was `23`. Changed the `compileSDKVersion` to `27` which fixed the error.